# System.OutOfMemoryException When using this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke wpf datagrid ObservableCollection

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, datagrid

This function runs in a thread:

```
private void uReadBinaryDataset()
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(m_sFileName))
        {
            using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(sr.BaseStream))
            {
                long read = 0;
                long count = br.BaseStream.Length;
                while (read < count)
                {
                    long ticks = br.ReadInt64();
                    float fv1 = br.ReadSingle();
                    float fv2 = br.ReadSingle();
                    this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action)delegate
                    {
                        liDataSet.Add(new DataFormat(ticks, fv1, fv2));
                    });
                    read += sizeof(long) + 2 * sizeof(float);
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

liDataSet is an ObservableCollection and uReadBinaryDataset is a member of my wpf window
That gives this exception

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Comment: Ok, you read a lot of data and got out of memory. So, what is a question?

Comment: You're using that BeginInvoke because otherwise it crashes?

Comment: @tym32167 : when i`m not using datagrid no exception thrown, how can i handle this error?

Comment: @rene yes in this case cause another exception, using ui in another thread problem!

Comment: @HamidSOS what kind of answer are you expecting? Have you invvestigated how much memory eats you program with datagrid/with something else? Obviously, when you storing you data in datagrid - this takes more memory than do not store data anywhere.